lc29hAA reading gps coords esp32
I can't access the NMEA data off my gps using UART pins. Im using pins 16 rx and 17 tx on my esp32 wroom in vscode platformio. The data is not being transmitted to my console and gps.locaiton.isvalid is false. I understand there is some setup to do prior to with but i am unsure if this is right. my goal is to recive RTCM data and for this device to act as a base station and send to my iphone for corrected coords.:
I was expecting this to work but they are null.
  // Send commands to the LC29H module
  sendCommand("$PAIR434,124"); // Open 1005 
  delay(100); // Allow some time for the command to execute
  sendCommand("$PAIR432,122"); // Output MSM7 information
  delay(100); // Allow some time for the command to execute
  sendCommand("$PAIR436,1*26"); // Open ephemeris 


while (mySerial.available() > 0) {
  Serial.println("gps is encoding...");
    //gps.encode(mySerial.read());
    Serial.write(mySerial.read()); // Print received data to the serial monitor

  }

    // Collect GPS samples to calculate the average
    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) {
        if (gps.location.isValid()) {
            totalLat += gps.location.lat();
            totalLng += gps.location.lng();
            totalAlt += gps.altitude.meters();
            validSamples++;

            // Check RTK status in GGA
            // if (gps.gga.fix_quality == 4) {
            //     Serial.println("RTK Fixed position.");
            // } else if (gps.gga.fix_quality == 5) {
            //     Serial.println("RTK Float position.");
            // } else {
            //     Serial.println("No RTK Fix. GNSS Quality: " + String(gps.gga.fix_quality));
            // }
        } //else {


Pease show the connection diagram on which of the two UART of the LC29H(AA) you are connecting to and how it is connect to ESP32? What board rate you are using? When you send command like $PAIR434,124, it will echo back some data, what it is shown on the Serial Monitor?
